# USAR TRIGGER EN SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy incluyendo un trigger en mi tabla DataIn y tengo dudas con respecto a si estoy tomando bien los valores dentro del trigger.  La idea es que al actualizar un status dentro de DataIn, se inserte un nuevo registro en una tabla ubicada en otra base de datos (MANIFIESTO), al hacer ese insert, también debe recuperar el id de esa tabla y actualizar una tercera tabla (MOD_WEB) ubicada en la misma base de datos donde hizo la inserción anterior. (espero haberme explicado)

```
CREATE  TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_crear_manifiesto]
ON [dbo].[DataIn]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @id_mod_web int,
        @a int, 
        @ID_I INT

    IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TMP_MANIFIESTOS') IS NOT NULL                        DROP TABLE #TMP_MANIFIESTOS

        select @ID_I = @@IDENTITY   

        SELECT  @id_mod_web =  A.ID_MOD_WEB 
             FROM Report..MOD_WEB A 
                INNER JOIN Report..MOD_DETALLE B on (A.ID_MOD_WEB = B.ID_MOD_WEB)
                INNER JOIN (SELECT R.DocEntry, count(DISTINCT R.U_SEI_ORIGEN_STOCK) as 'Origen' FROM  PRODUCTIVO..RDR1 R with(nolock) GROUP BY R.DocEntry) F ON (A.ORDR=F.DocEntry)
                INNER JOIN MultiVendeV2..DataIn I ON I.externalId collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS = CONCAT(A.PEDIDO_WEB_LARGO collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS , '-01') 

            WHERE A.origen = 'vtex'  
                AND B.CODIGO != 'RPAPRECIO'   
                AND ISNULL(A.RETIRO_TIENDA, '') != '' 
                AND F.Origen = 1 
                AND A.NRO_BOLETA NOT IN (SELECT ORN.U_SEI_FOREF FROM BADAMAX_PRODUCTIVO..ORIN AS ORN WHERE  ORN.U_SEI_FOREF = A.NRO_BOLETA AND ORN.U_SEI_INREF = 39  )
                AND I.EstadoMV LIKE 'Listo para el envío' 
                AND I.FechaEnTienda IS NOT NULL
                AND I.id = @ID_I 
                AND A.ID_MANIFIESTO IS NULL 
                --AND A.FECHA >= '2020-02-24'
                ORDER BY FECHA DESC 

                IF(@id_mod_web > 0) 
                    BEGIN
                        INSERT INTO [Report].[dbo].[MOD_MANIFIESTO] (ID_USUARIO, FECHA, COMENTARIO, TRANSPORTE) VALUES (1, GETDATE(), 'RETIRO EN TIENDA CON PRODUCTOS QUE SALEN DEL STOCK DE TIENDA', 'BADAMAX' )  
                        select @a = @@IDENTITY 
                        SELECT @a 
                        UPDATE Report..MOD_WEB  SET ID_RT_ESTADO = 1, ID_MANIFIESTO = @a, ESTADO_REVISION = 1, FECHA_REVISION = GETDATE() WHERE ID_MOD_WEB =  @id_mod_web 
                    END
```

Mi duda es, ¿cómo doy continuidad al trigger para salir de dudas de si está haciendo bien todo el proceso? ¿en sql puedo tener un old.nombredeliddelatablaquedisparaeltrigger en lugar de estar haciendo @identity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que no vas por buen camino. Te voy a explicar otro modo de realizarlo y como se puede enfocar, pero hay cosas que con el escenario que planteas no voy a tocar, y creo que si deberías de modificar.

Voy a intentar ir por partes. 
@@Identity, no es la manera de recuperar los valores insertados en un trigger. No es por las diferentes utilizaciones que muestras de @@identity o Scope_identity, sino porque en una tabla se pueden insertar varios registros simultaneamente, y no te funcionará correctamente.

Para saber lo que se ha insertado se utiliza la pseudo-tabla inserted, que tiene la misma estructura que la tabla de la que se gestiona el trigger. Por tanto inserted es igual que DataIn tiene las mismas columnas y todos los datos nuevos que tienen las filas actualizadas con los nuevos valores. En iguales circunstancias esta la pseudo-tabla deleted, pero esta tiene los valores justo anteriores a la modificación.

Por tanto sin meterme de lleno en las querys, que creo que se pueden mejorar bastante, puedes crear una variable de tabla, que tenga el id y el id_mod_web

```
CREATE  TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_crear_manifiesto]
ON [dbo].[DataIn]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @id_mod_web int,
    @a int, 
    @ID_I INT


        DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID INT, ID_MOD_WEB INT)

    INSERT INTO @TABLE 
    SELECT  INSERTED.ID, A.ID_MOD_WEB 
         FROM Report..MOD_WEB A 
            INNER JOIN Report..MOD_DETALLE B on (A.ID_MOD_WEB = B.ID_MOD_WEB)
            INNER JOIN 
                (SELECT R.DocEntry, count(DISTINCT R.U_SEI_ORIGEN_STOCK) as 'Origen' 
                    FROM  PRODUCTIVO..RDR1 R with(nolock) 
                    GROUP BY R.DocEntry) F ON (A.ORDR=F.DocEntry)
            INNER JOIN MultiVendeV2..DataIn I ON I.externalId collate  SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS = CONCAT(A.PEDIDO_WEB_LARGO collate  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS , '-01') 
            -- MEZCLAS LO QUE SE HA MODIFICADO CON EL RESTO DE CONJUNTOS, Y ASÍ SOLO  TIENES LOS REGISTROS MODIFICADOS, BIEN SEA 1 O VARIOS.
            INNER JOIN INSERTED ON I.ID = INSERTED.ID

        WHERE A.origen = 'vtex'  
            AND B.CODIGO != 'RPAPRECIO'   
            AND ISNULL(A.RETIRO_TIENDA, '') != '' 
            AND F.Origen = 1 
            AND A.NRO_BOLETA NOT IN (SELECT ORN.U_SEI_FOREF FROM BADAMAX_PRODUCTIVO..ORIN AS ORN WHERE  ORN.U_SEI_FOREF = A.NRO_BOLETA AND ORN.U_SEI_INREF  = 39  )
            AND I.EstadoMV LIKE 'Listo para el envío' 
            AND I.FechaEnTienda IS NOT NULL

            AND A.ID_MANIFIESTO IS NULL 
            --AND A.FECHA >= '2020-02-24'


            IF(@id_mod_web > 0) 
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO [Report].[dbo].[MOD_MANIFIESTO] (ID_USUARIO, FECHA,  COMENTARIO, TRANSPORTE) 
                    VALUES (1, GETDATE(), 'RETIRO EN TIENDA CON PRODUCTOS QUE SALEN DEL STOCK DE TIENDA', 'BADAMAX' )  


                    UPDATE R  SET ID_RT_ESTADO = 1, ID_MANIFIESTO = @a, ESTADO_REVISION = 1, FECHA_REVISION = GETDATE() 
                    FROM REPORT..MOD_WEB INNER JOIN @TABLE T ON  R.ID_MOD_WEB = T.ID_MOD_WEB

                END
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Javi fer2 @javi-fer2 estuve leyendo que la manera de obtener los campos modificados era con esas tabla "virtuales" inserted and deleted de sql server (no existe el OLD como en postgresql) Sin embargo aún me queda una duda, cómo recupero el id del manifiesto insertado en  IF(@id_mod_web > 0) 
          que lo necesito en esta parte UPDATE R  SET ID_RT_ESTADO = 1, ID_MANIFIESTO = @a----------------------------> id del manifiesto

Comment: Hola Virginia: old = deleted básicamente. Los ids, los puedes recuperar con output Insert into ...... https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 Echale un ojo al enlace, y si tienes problemas, te lo ajusto un poco más.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su explicación, me ha servido muchísimo, logré rehacer lo que estaba mal y ahora funciona.  Dejaré la solución como respuesta a éste tema por si alguien mas tiene la misma duda. @Javi fer2

Comment: De nada Virginia.

Answer (score 0):

A lo que entiendo de tu codigo creo que solo seria hacerle esta moficacion ya que el ultimo parametro es lo que podria estarte dando problemas ya que llamas al mismo id_mod_web en vez de el id de la tabla manifiestos

```
 IF(@id_mod_web > 0) 
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO [Report].[dbo].[MOD_MANIFIESTO] (ID_USUARIO, FECHA, COMENTARIO, TRANSPORTE) VALUES (1, GETDATE(), 'RETIRO EN TIENDA CON PRODUCTOS QUE SALEN DEL STOCK DE TIENDA', 'BADAMAX' )  
                    select @a = @@IDENTITY 

                    UPDATE Report..MOD_WEB  SET ID_RT_ESTADO = 1, ID_MANIFIESTO = @a, ESTADO_REVISION = 1, FECHA_REVISION = GETDATE() WHERE ID_MOD_WEB =  @a 
             END
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí el trigger completo que me ha funcionado:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_crear_manifiesto]
ON [dbo].[DataIn]
AFTER UPDATE
AS  
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @id_mod_web int,
  @a int,
  @ID_I INT

DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID INT, ID_MOD_WEB INT)
DECLARE @TABLE_MANIFIESTO TABLE (MANIFIESTO_ID INT)

INSERT INTO @TABLE 
SELECT  INSERTED.ID, A.ID_MOD_WEB 
     FROM Report..MOD_WEB A 
        INNER JOIN Report..MOD_DETALLE B on (A.ID_MOD_WEB = B.ID_MOD_WEB)
        INNER JOIN 
            (SELECT R.DocEntry, count(DISTINCT R.U_SEI_ORIGEN_STOCK) as 'Origen' 
                FROM  PRODUCTIVO..RDR1 R with(nolock) 
                GROUP BY R.DocEntry) F ON (A.ORDR=F.DocEntry)
        INNER JOIN Multi..DataIn I WITH(NOLOCK) ON I.externalId collate  SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS = CONCAT(A.PEDIDO_WEB_LARGO collate  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS , '-01') 
        INNER JOIN INSERTED ON I.ID = INSERTED.ID

    WHERE A.origen = 'vtex'  
        AND B.CODIGO != 'RPAPRECIO'   
        AND ISNULL(A.RETIRO_TIENDA, '') != '' 
        AND F.Origen = 1 
        AND A.NRO_BOLETA NOT IN (SELECT ORN.U_SEI_FOREF FROM PRODUCTIVO..ORIN AS ORN WHERE  ORN.U_SEI_FOREF = A.NRO_BOLETA AND ORN.U_SEI_INREF  = 39  )
        AND I.EstadoMV LIKE 'Listo para el envío' 
        AND I.FechaEnTienda IS NOT NULL
        AND A.ID_MANIFIESTO IS NULL 


        SELECT @id_mod_web = ID_MOD_WEB FROM @TABLE L INNER JOIN INSERTED E ON L.ID = E.ID 

        IF(@id_mod_web > 0) 
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO [Report].[dbo].[MOD_WEB_MANIFIESTO] (ID_USUARIO, FECHA,  COMENTARIO, TRANSPORTE) 
                OUTPUT INSERTED.ID_MANIFIESTO INTO @TABLE_MANIFIESTO  
                VALUES (1, GETDATE(), CONCAT('RETIRO EN TIENDA CON PRODUCTOS QUE SALEN DEL STOCK DE TIENDA ', @id_mod_web ), 'TRANSPORTE' )  

                SELECT @a = MANIFIESTO_ID FROM @TABLE_MANIFIESTO     
                UPDATE Report..MOD_WEB  SET ID_RT_ESTADO = 1, ID_MANIFIESTO = @a, ESTADO_REVISION = 1, FECHA_REVISION = GETDATE() WHERE ID_MOD_WEB =  @id_mod_web 

            END

END
```